# Eliminar options de distintos select

Tags: jquery

Tengo 3 `selects`, quiero que cuando se elija uno se borre de los otros 2 pero sin borrar el primero. Es posible?

```
<select class="sel">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
      var opcion = $(this).val();
      $('.sel').each(function(){
          $('.sel option[value="'+opcion+'"]').remove();
      })
    });
</script>
```

Me está eliminando el valor del SELECT de donde lo saqué. Como puedo prevenir eso?

Comment: quieres eliminar el valor? o los select?

Comment: El valor que ya se ha elegido

Comment: por decir elimino el valor 1 del select 1, se deberia eliminar el valor 1 de los otros 2?

Comment: Si seleccione el valor 1 del primer select se deben eliminar el mismo valor de los otros 2

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, no se si es lo que buscabas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifique tu `script` dejándolo de esta manera:

```
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
  $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

Lo que hace es:

1. Del `select` cualquiera que se buscara de los elementos hermanos para buscar los elementos hermanos uso `.siblings()` el cual me hace una busqueda de todos los `select`
2. Después busco los `options` con `.find()` en el cual le digo que va a buscar el elemento que contenga el valor seleccionado del `select` que cambio y queda de esta forma `.find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]')`
3. Elimino ese elemento de los `selects` con `.remove()`

```js
$(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
  $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: elimine mi respuesta, por que esta respuesta es mucho mejor, +1

Comment: Funciona :O Gracias