# Eliminar option de select sin intervenir un div

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo este código en PHP que me repite 10 veces el mismo select con la misma información.

```
  for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++)
  {
      $output.='
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Prioridad '.$i.' de horario</label><br>
        <select class="form-control selectDisable">
          <option selected disabled>Elige una opción</option>
          <option value="1">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Lunes</option>
          <option value="2">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Martes</option>
          <option value="3">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Miércoles</option>
          <option value="4">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Jueves</option>
          <option value="5">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Viernes</option>
          <option value="6">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Sábado</option>
          <option value="7">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break:  00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Domingo</option>
        </select>
      </div>';
  }
```

Esto tengo con Jquery que me elimina la opción seleccionada en los demás select

```
  $(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
  });
```

El problema es que no lo ejecuta, al parecer por el `<div class="form-group">` ya que al parecer no está encontrando hermanos dentro del mismo DIV.

Ya había hecho la pregunta anteriormente aqui:

> [Eliminar options de distintos select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43803/eliminar-options-de-distintos-select)

Insisto, si quito el div del form-group lo hace bien, pero como puedo manejarlo con esa clase, he pensado en

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.selectDisable').siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
  });
```

Pero no me salió, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay un fallo en ese último código que es el que hace que no funcione:

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.selectDisable').siblings().find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

El `siblings()` está mal colocado. No quieres los hermanos del `select`, quieres los hermanos del `.form-group` que son los que van a contener los otros `select`. Para ello mueve el `siblings()` antes del `find(".selectDisable")`.

Con ese cambio, el código quedaría así y ya te debería funcionar:

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').siblings().find('.selectDisable').find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

Pero aún podrías simplificar un poco más el código porque realmente ya no necesitarías dos `find` seguidos: podrías unirlos en uno solo para que fuese algo más eficiente:

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').siblings().find('.selectDisable option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
});
```

Aquí te dejo una demo con sólo 3 `select`:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selectDisable', function() {
  $(this).closest('.form-group').siblings().find('.selectDisable option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Prioridad 1 de horario</label>
  <br>
  <select class="form-control selectDisable">
    <option selected disabled>Elige una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Lunes</option>
    <option value="2">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Martes</option>
    <option value="3">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Miércoles</option>
    <option value="4">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Jueves</option>
    <option value="5">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Viernes</option>
    <option value="6">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Sábado</option>
    <option value="7">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Domingo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Prioridad 2 de horario</label>
  <br>
  <select class="form-control selectDisable">
    <option selected disabled>Elige una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Lunes</option>
    <option value="2">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Martes</option>
    <option value="3">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Miércoles</option>
    <option value="4">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Jueves</option>
    <option value="5">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Viernes</option>
    <option value="6">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Sábado</option>
    <option value="7">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Domingo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Prioridad 3 de horario</label>
  <br>
  <select class="form-control selectDisable">
    <option selected disabled>Elige una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Lunes</option>
    <option value="2">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Martes</option>
    <option value="3">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Miércoles</option>
    <option value="4">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Jueves</option>
    <option value="5">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Viernes</option>
    <option value="6">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Sábado</option>
    <option value="7">Horario: 00:00 - 00:00 Break: 00:00 - 00:00 Descanso: Domingo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Una cosa: con esto borras, pero no reactivas si el usuario cambia de opción

Comment: Si es la idea, agradezco tu apoyo

Answer (score 0):

otra opción puede ser

```
$(document).on('change','.selectDisable',function(){
   $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]',this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hola juliana, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿por qué o cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta? Lee [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla).